# Passing an Array as Arguments NOT user function, in PHP

Tags: php, arguments, pack

I have the following code:

```
$bin = "\x04\x00\xa0\x00\x04\x00\xa0\x00";
$unpack_data = unpack("C*", $bin);
$arr = array($unpack_data[1], $unpack_data[2], $unpack_data[3]);
```

How can I pass an array $arr to a ***pack()*** function? The only thing that I can make:

```
$res = pack("C*", $unpack_data[1], $unpack_data[2], $unpack_data[3]);
```

but the length and content of the array are getting in the course of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(['C*'], $unpack_data))
```

Answer (score 2):

[New php 5.6 syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new) allow this

```
pack('C*', ...$unpack_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = pack('C*',$arr)

//hope this might help you
```